# Lanuch Activity located inside a jar file

Tags: android

I saw many posts related to that topic but still with no clear answer,
I want my activity to be compresses as a jar file and than launch one of the activities from this jar file from another application using startActivity.
i've already created a jar and imported it to the bin folder of the application (tried also add the jar at the build path but still can't launch any activity).the problem with it located on bin folder two manifest files one for the application and another for the jar file 
is there a solution for that and can it be done at all?

Comment: Have you loaded the JAR file via URLClassLoader?

Comment: no just imported it locally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the activity definition to your application's manifest.
android will not look at the manifest located in the jar.
All activities, services, broadcast receivers and permissions that you use and are defined in the jar need to be declared in your manifest.

**EDIT**
Also note that an easier solution would be to make the code you have in the jar to an Android library project, this way android will take care of the manifest and the releveant UI resources that you would use (layouts, drawables etc...)

Comment: So i need to copy the manifest file from the jar file to the application manifest, and delete the manifest file from my lib folder?

Comment: You don't need the whole manifest, just the definitions of components that you will use and permissions that they require. The manifest in the jar has no effect

Answer (score 0):

you absolutely **HAVE** to define the activity in the manifest of the app that is compiled. The other manifests do not contribute to the finished app *at all*.
Same is true for all required libraries, phone features and rights definitions.
A typical library manifest that I use looks like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="org.meredrica.example.library"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

</manifest>
```